# Matplotlib: highlight range at the bottom of plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

I need to produce a plot with certain ranges highlighted. The problem is that I cannot use `axvspan` that would fill the span area from top to bottom. I need to limit the spanned area only to the bottom, as can be seen in the image below, where the range 0.5-1.5 is highlighted:

[image]

Is there a way to achieve this in matplotlib?

Comment: You can define the boundaries of your rectangle (``xmin``, ``xmax``, ``ymin``, ``ymax``) in ``axvspan``. Otherwise, you can manually specify the coordinates of your polygon and use ``fill``.

Comment: Thank you @Kefeng91! It seems `ymax` in `axvspan` was all I needed. Want to make your comment an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the boundaries of your rectangle (`xmin`, `xmax`, `ymin`, `ymax`) in `axvspan`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-1.0, 2.0, 301)
y = np.sin(2.0 * np.pi * x)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.axvspan(0.5, 1.5, ymax=0.05, color="gray")
plt.show()
```

Note that `ymin` and `ymax` are relative coordinates (between 0 and 1).